# Pbft consensus with 4 VPs

Tags: hyperledger

I have set up a dev network consisting of 4VPs using the pbft consensus.

I am trying to test the behaviour of the VPs when one of them is down.

- Step one

While the 4 VPs are running , i have deployed a chain code (chaincode_example02).

Checking localhost:7050/chain -> return **2**

- Step two

I shutdown one of the VP using (docker stop containerID)

Now when i execute an Invoke transaction and recheck the chain length:

localhost:7050/chain -> it still returns **2**.

- Step three

I restart the VP (from step 2) , and the i see that the invoke transaction (from step 2) is executed automatically and the chain size is now 3

localhost:7050/chain -> now returns **3**.

My understanding is that with 4VP using the pbft consensus, we have tolerance for 1 faulty VP .If that is the case, then the invoke transaction should have been executed in step2.

Can someone please advise if that is the expected result and why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: how long did you wait before step 3 ? please try waiting a little bit longer before step 3 and check the block height

Comment: @SufiyanGhori i did, still the same , i waited for about 5 min .. nothing happened.. but as soon as i start the container(step3) all the transaction get  executed.

Comment: please read this, https://github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric/issues/933

Comment: This is referring to an unsupported Fabric version, one of the pre-release developer previews. Consider closing this question unless you feel it also applies to a released version.

Comment: The PBFT consensus is not yet available in the released versions of Fabric. Keep an eye out for SBFT consensus in a future release.